# Download file as csv when running script from command line

Tags: php, command-line, argv, fputcsv

When I run my php script from a browser, I get a csv file to automatically download to the client using `$fp = fopen('php://output', "w");`, `fputcsv` and the appropriate `header` tags. It works very nicely.

When I run my script from the command line using `php index.php 2014` ("2014" being the argv I am passing in), then the contents of what would normally go in to the csv actually appears in the command line box.

How can I get my code to still download a csv file when using the command line?

If it matters I am running ubuntu using Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Comment: show your command you run in your command line

Comment: You can't "download" anything using the command line in the browser sense - there is no HTTP client for that. You need to write the file to a folder or set destination when running from the command line.

Comment: @Bulk - Yep. I was being a little optimistic and generally confused about the client/server side divide.

Comment: Yeah I think you might be - the command line is for direct interaction with the server - it's not something you want clients involved with generally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the line as follows, where $$filepath is the file path name.

```
$fp = fopen($$filepath, "w");
```

Comment: I had that initially.. And you are correct. But it would download to the server. Not the client.

Comment: Yes file will be generated in the system whose terminal the script is running. What you meant by client machine in this case?

Comment: I mean, so the user can save it to their desktop for example. But judging by the responses I am getting on this question, I am starting to understand that it may not be possible. Which is fine

Comment: Then the php script should generate the csv and return the filepath, so that from the client machine you can download from the server side using another php code.

Answer (score 1):

If you display the content of the CSV on the index.php file, you can do this command:

**php index.php 2014 > my_csv.csv**